# Find the 3x3 matrix which the system is inconsistent.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the value of K such that the system is inconsistent.

$$\begin{cases}x + y + 2z = 7\\
-2x - 2y + Kz = -14\\
3x + 3y + 6z = 14\end{cases}$$

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 2 & 7\\
-2 & -2 & k & -14\\
3 & 3 & 6 & 14
\end{array}\right)$$
Adding $2\cdot\mathrm{Row}_1$ to $\mathrm{Row}_2$ and subtracting $3\cdot\mathrm{Row}_1$ from $\mathrm{Row}_3$, we get
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 1 & 2 & 7\\
0 & 0 & k+4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -7
\end{array}\right)$$
So, $\mathrm{Row}_3$ now states that $0=-7$ and inconsistency is guaranteed no matter what the other rows might state.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $K=-4$ and divide the second equation through by $-2$ and the third equation through by $3$, you see the left hand sides of the second and third equations are the same, but the right hands aren't, so the system is inconsistent.